# Copy local SqlServer database with visual studio solution

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I've created a simple sports store (From Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 freeman) that I keep on a flash drive, due to working on my desktop computer, laptop, or a lab computer on campus. Is there an easy way to bring the database tables along with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd recommend looking into a version control system (SVN, Git, etc). Even if you don't use it for versioning, it will--at a minimum--help you sync your code between different computers.

The simplest (yet most basic) way of bringing your database along with the code is just to add a SQL schema script along side your code and run it on the local SQL server on each machine. However, this approach has the limitation of not handling schema *updates* very well...which brings me to my recommended solution: use an ORM (i.e. Entity Framework) and let it handle the creation of the database. If your schema needs to change, it will automatically generate migration scripts that can update the database on your other machines.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I ended up adding the .mdf to my App Data folder and that solved all of my problems